# Existence of solution to system of linear equations with stochastic coefficients matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, numerical-linear-algebra, markov-process

Given an underdetermined or determined system of linear equations, can anything be said about existence of a solution if the coefficients matrix is a stochastic matrix, i.e., its rows sum up to 1? I know that [Rouche-Capelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem) gives general criteria for consistency of any system of linear equations. I am interested in any criteria beyond those given by R-C theorem, specifically for stochastic coefficient matrices. I appreciate any pointers/insights.